# Tensorflow Tutorial Error (InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP])

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Computer Vision and I'm following the tutorial on Tensorflow [Image Classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification).
I came across this error message when trying to visualise the dataset. I am using a different dataset though.

Here is the error message: (Can I get some help?)

```
InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
[[{{node decode_image/cond_jpeg/else/_1/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/else/_20/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/else/_39/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert/Assert}}]]
```

This is the code that created the error:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, labels in training_set.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

Comment: Could you post more information so that I can try to recreate the issue? Ideally the dataset you are using and any code you are using to pre-process the dataset.

Comment: This is a link to the Kaggle notebook I'm working on. https://www.kaggle.com/quarshiea/notebook1fac2b194b. It has quite a large dataset and the code is there. Thanks!

Comment: Check this similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13044. Several workarounds are mentioned take a look.Thanks!